# How to hide columns using TanStack Ver 8

Tags: typescript, tanstack-table

Using Tanstack table ver 8, how do I dynamically hide specific columns?

```
I have column defined
{
        header: "Case Number",
        accessorKey: "caseNumber",
        visible: false, // use this value
},
```

I am trying to use the *"visible: false"* to hide the column when the table is rendered.

There is a *columnVisibility* setting, but I cant seem to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ver 8:

Function GetInVisibleColumn() takes an array of finalColumnDef and filters out the columns that have the visible property set to **false**. It then creates a new object (removedColumn) where the keys are the accessorKey properties of the invisible columns, and the values are set to false.

```
const columns = useMemo(
....
{
        header: "Case Number",
        accessorKey: "caseNumber",
        visible: false,
},
```

then

```
const tableInstance: any = useReactTable({
...
initialState: {
        columnVisibility: GetInVisibleColumn(finalColumnDef),
```

```
function GetInVisibleColumn(finalColumnDef: any) {

  let inVisibleColumns = finalColumnDef.filter(
    (col: { visible: boolean }) => col.visible === false
  );
  
  const removedColumn = {} as Record<string, boolean>;
  for (const item of inVisibleColumns) {
    removedColumn[item.accessorKey] = false;
  }

  return removedColumn;
}
```